# How to get web scraping flask app to show new web scraping results every time the flask app's web page is reloaded in browser?

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, waitress

My flask app does some webscraping (using the requests library) and then displays the results on an html template (info.html).

The flask app works but it does the webscraping only once (when the flask app is started), meaning that if I refresh the web page later, it still shows the same old webscraping results as on the first time.

**I would like the web page to refresh the results from the webscraping every time the page is reloaded in the browser**. Right now the results are not refreshed unless I kill the flask process and run it again - is this normal for flask, and if so, how can I get the app to run the scraping again every time I reload the tab?

I'm using waitress, and basically the code looks like this:

```
from waitress import serve
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def index():

    ... webscraping stuff here ...
    return render_template("info.html", news_sites = news_sites, ... 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

I start the app with

```
python3 infoflask.py
```

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to make an app scraping with FLASK, one is to use the BEATIFULSOUP 4 library for flashing which manages to generate what you ask that every time you enter your app you refresh the scraping data, I leave you a link to a tutorial

https://dev.to/blazephoenix/webscraping-in-python-with-flask-and-beautifulsoup-4-1pkl